# How to debug custom loader / resolve hooks with --experimental-modules?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Node introduced 8.5 introduced [resolve hooks with --experimental-modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolve_hook) I am trying to develop one resolve hook but can't seem to debug it using Webstork or just plain --inspect.

I am on Node 8.9.1 (also tried 9.2.0)

[This sample loader has debugger; statement](https://github.com/yogeshgadge/mjs-mixed-loaders/blob/master/src/custom-loader.mjs) and I am running it like this as per the documentation:-

`NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-modules --loader ./src/custom-loader.mjs' node --inspect apple.mjs`

or

`node --inspect --experimental-modules --loader ./src/custom-loader.mjs`

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using node 10.4, this command works:

```
node --inspect-brk --experimental-modules --loader ./loader.mjs index.mjs
```